# Swift closure: Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Bool' to expected argument type

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm working with the `filter()` method in Swift, but encountering a problem I can't seem to reproduce in a playground.

**Edit:** Uploaded an example project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ce5uyxnpb0mndf/WeirdSwifty.zip?dl=0

I have a `Card` struct which contains a `CardType` enum:

```
struct Card {
    var name = ""
    var type : CardType

    enum CardType {
        case Red
        case Black
    }
}
```

And a `Player` class which maintains an array of these `Card` items:

```
class Player {
    var hand : [Card]

    init() {
        hand = ...
    }

    func redCards() -> [Card] {
        return hand.filter({ (card) -> Bool in
            return card.type == .Red
        })
    }
}
```

However, Xcode is throwing an error no matter how I try to format this closure. I even let Xcode autocomplete the closure signature/body, thinking I had a syntax error, but it keeps recreating it the same (correct?) way:

[image]

I've also tried editing what Xcode automatically generates and providing a simpler version, to no avail:

[image]

Similarly:

[image]

As I mention I'm unable to reproduce this in a simple playground example, but I can't narrow down what's actually *causing* the issue in my primary project.

This is the only error in my project, and if I comment out the method containing the `filter()` call, it builds properly.

Is this error a common red herring for some other actual issue?

*Note: Using Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)*

Comment: Try giving card an explicit type:  `return hand.filter({ (card: Card) -> Bool in
            return card.type == .Red
        })`

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me... maybe try cleaning your build folder?

Comment: Don't you have `card` or `Card` defined somewhere else in the same scope?  The code compiles fine for me too.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a compiled project (instead of the Playground)?

Comment: Thanks for the interest so far guys. I've uploaded a project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ce5uyxnpb0mndf/WeirdSwifty.zip?dl=0 It works great for me in a playground, but for some reason this project (maybe it's the type nesting/scoping?) exhibits the issue. Cleaning the project, the build folder, etc. doesn't help.

Comment: Huh that's weird... if you bring the `Card` declaration into the same file as the `Player` declaration, it will work fine. Definitely file a bug report on that one.

Comment: @originaluser2 Thanks. I had my suspicions, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Will file.

Comment: If you split the definition of `CardType` from `Card`, you find that it works when `CardType` is in the same file as the filter, but not when it is in the other file.  It doesn't matter where `Card` is defined. The key to the problem seems to be `.Red`.  Fully specifying `Card.CardType.Red` resolves the issue as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something flakey is happening with Swift's type inference.  Give `card` an explicit type and it will work.

```
return hand.filter({ (card: Card) -> Bool in return card.type == .Red })
```

You don't need the return type or the return:

```
return hand.filter({ (card: Card) in card.type == .Red })
```

Note: this works also:

```
return hand.filter({ ($0 as Card).type == .Red })
```

Fully specifying the `.Red` enum value resolves the issue as well:

```
return hand.filter({ $0.type == Card.CardType.Red })
```

It was mentioned in the comments that if you move the definition of `Card` into the same file as the filter, that it works.  In fact, if you split the definition of the `CardType` enum out from `Card` and just move `CardType` into the file with the filter, it works.

Comment: That did it, thanks - will radar the issue. The `return` is also not necessary, it's inferred if a single statement has a return value that matches the expected return type of the closure: `return hand.filter({ (card: Card) in card.type == .Red })`

Comment: @CraigOtis It has something to do with the order of compilation. It works if `Card` is declared in the same file as `Player`.

Comment: Fully specifying the enum type works as well! `return hand.filter({ $0.type == Card.CardType.Red })`